# browserLink error when run Blazor server side project

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, blazor-server-side

When I run and change ervitoment dev to stag in Blazor server side that time face below error.

> browserLink:77 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'href')

Please check this image.

[image]

Comment: I don't have this error, can you share your launchSettings?

Comment: This error was faced after deploying the build on the server.

Comment: Are using IIS ?

Comment: No, I am using the Azure App service.

Comment: This link could help you https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Answer (score 0):

Need to add below code in startup service

```
services.AddServerSideBlazor().AddCircuitOptions(options => { options.DetailedErrors = true; });
```